# What does Chris Evans have in his ear? Earpiece or shadow?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

I'm a marvel fan and I just noticed Chris Evans has a black shadow in his left ear when he is on set. I can't tell if it's an earpiece or a shadow.

The last picture has no black shadow so I put it here to help with comparison if needed.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Looks like an ear-wig - communications device so the Avengers can talk to each other.  Might also be practical - to help him hear the director, etc., on a noisy set.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim! when i tell you it was driving me mad, i wasnt joking. Im leaning towards it being so Chris can hear the director. I noticed the actors around him dont seem to have it on, so im guessing either i just havent come across pictures where they do, or Chris is the only one to prefer it. Could also be to help him learn his lines. The obvious idea is its Avengers communitcations, but since no other actors have it, must be for practical use.

Comment: update: spoke to someone that works on set via twitter, they confirmed it is a hearing aid which RDJ also wears here and there.

Comment: you can provide your own answer below.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: spoke to someone that works on set via twitter, they confirmed it is a hearing aid which RDJ also wears here and there

(thanks tim!)

here’s the tweet from the Atlanta (where marvel mostly films their movies) set person: https://twitter.com/atlantafilming/status/983140197956190208?s=21

Comment: You should put the source included in your answer to make it far more plausible

Comment: It will be better if you share that tweeter reply